# docker login in shell script dont work

Tags: shell, docker

I can not make the command "Docker Login" with  "shell", I use this command for this type of access, more "Docker Login" it does not seem to serve.

```
 echo -e 'user\nPassword\nemail@test.com' | (docker login)
```

returns `Username: Password: EOF` not complete the operation

Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker documentation describes how the credentials are stored in a file called ".dockercfg":

- http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerrepos/

Comment: Link is redirected to Getting Started as of November 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I followed below command in shell script and it's working as expected. It's a one time setup.. Next time when you run your script comment out the below line.. Though you comment out, shell executes the script as it saves the credentials in config.json file. Make sure, credentials are not changed or don't logout.

`docker login -e email address -u username -p password`